# How do I use a JFrame class as main class?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, program-entry-point

### I'm trying to build a calculator.

I've developed the interface using the Swing plug-in (containers and controls), but when I try to run my program it says the package needs a main class.

Already tried to create a main class and call the Calc() JFrame class, but it didn't work.

Take a look at the code:

```
public class Calc extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public Calc() {
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `public static void main(String[] args)`? Also, you say "_call the Calc() JFrame class_" but in the code you posted `Calc` is a `JPanel`, not a `JFrame`.

Comment: Where may I write the psvm?

Comment: Pretty much anywhere really but I would put it inside the class that extends or creates the JFrame.

Comment: @csmckelvey, Don't extend JFame. You are not changing the functionality of the frame. The recommended approach is to create a JPanel and add the panel to the instance of the frame that you create in the main() method. Take a look at the tutorial link I provided. It shows complete code that can be copied and compiled.

Comment: I don't know if OP is changing the functionality of the frame.

Comment: He is not. Adding components to the frame does not change the functionality of the frame.

Comment: I've created a JFrame class, and it already have the `psvm`. Thanks for the clarification, but now I'll have to design the whole calculator (visually) again, hehe.

Comment: @EstêvãoRolim, No, don't extend the frame. Read the tutorial. I gave you that link for a reason. You are a beginner, so why not learn how to code Swing properly from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a main() method to execute your class.

Take a look at the `FrameDemo` example code found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a basic example to get you started.

```
/* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class FrameDemo {

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
 * this method should be invoked from the
 * event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the main+invokeLater; the FrameDemo is a bit long-winded. Though that demo app is quite useful.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: I don't know what's happening.
I am new in Java Swing, and I'm using a plugin that generates all the interface code automatically, so then you just work on the position and logic of buttons, labels, etc.

Comment: That is the problem. Don't use an IDE to generate code because you don't know what the code does. You have been given a link to the Swing tutorial. It will show you how to write basic code for each Swing component. Only use an IDE to help in compiling and debugging the code.